# Spring Boot - how to allow CORS on REST Controller HTTP PUT

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cors

I'm my Spring Boot REST controller, I'm able to allow CORS for HTTP POST, but for some reason HTTP PUT is still being blocked.
I have placed my CORS decorator at the Controller level - HTTP PUT handler still being blocked.
Here is my controller:

```
package com.khoubyari.example.api.rest;

import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiParam;

import com.khoubyari.example.domain.Hotel;
import com.khoubyari.example.exception.DataFormatException;
import com.khoubyari.example.service.HotelService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/example/v1/hotels")
@Api(tags = {"hotels"})
//@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@CrossOrigin( origins = "*" , allowedHeaders = "*")
public class HotelController extends AbstractRestHandler {

    @Autowired
    private HotelService hotelService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "",
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = {"application/json", "application/xml"},
            produces = {"application/json", "application/xml"})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @ApiOperation(value = "Create a hotel resource.", notes = "Returns the URL of the new resource in the Location header.")
    public void createHotel(@RequestBody Hotel hotel,
                                 HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Hotel createdHotel = this.hotelService.createHotel(hotel);
        response.setHeader("Location", request.getRequestURL().append("/").append(createdHotel.getId()).toString());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = {"application/json", "application/xml"})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @ApiOperation(value = "Get a paginated list of all hotels.", notes = "The list is paginated. You can provide a page number (default 0) and a page size (default 100)")
    public
    @ResponseBody
    Page<Hotel> getAllHotel(@ApiParam(value = "The page number (zero-based)", required = true)
                                      @RequestParam(value = "page", required = true, defaultValue = DEFAULT_PAGE_NUM) Integer page,
                                      @ApiParam(value = "Tha page size", required = true)
                                      @RequestParam(value = "size", required = true, defaultValue = DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE) Integer size,
                                      HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        return this.hotelService.getAllHotels(page, size);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = {"application/json", "application/xml"})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @ApiOperation(value = "Get a single hotel.", notes = "You have to provide a valid hotel ID.")
    public
    @ResponseBody
    Hotel getHotel(@ApiParam(value = "The ID of the hotel.", required = true)
                             @PathVariable("id") Long id,
                             HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        Hotel hotel = this.hotelService.getHotel(id);
        checkResourceFound(hotel);
        return hotel;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}",
            method = RequestMethod.PUT,
            consumes = {"application/json", "application/xml"},
            produces = {"application/json", "application/xml"})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    @ApiOperation(value = "Update a hotel resource.", notes = "You have to provide a valid hotel ID in the URL and in the payload. The ID attribute can not be updated.")
    public void updateHotel(@ApiParam(value = "The ID of the existing hotel resource.", required = true)
                                 @PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody Hotel hotel,
                                 HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        checkResourceFound(this.hotelService.getHotel(id));
        if (id != hotel.getId()) throw new DataFormatException("ID doesn't match!");
        this.hotelService.updateHotel(hotel);
    }

    //todo: @ApiImplicitParams, @ApiResponses
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}",
            method = RequestMethod.DELETE,
            produces = {"application/json", "application/xml"})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    @ApiOperation(value = "Delete a hotel resource.", notes = "You have to provide a valid hotel ID in the URL. Once deleted the resource can not be recovered.")
    public void deleteHotel(@ApiParam(value = "The ID of the existing hotel resource.", required = true)
                                 @PathVariable("id") Long id, HttpServletRequest request,
                                 HttpServletResponse response) {
        checkResourceFound(this.hotelService.getHotel(id));
        this.hotelService.deleteHotel(id);
    }
}
```

What should I change in order for the HTTP PUT handler to allow updates?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify allowed methods explicitely like this in your CORS config (I'm using Kotlin and implementing `WebMvcConfigurer`):

```
override fun addCorsMappings(registry: CorsRegistry) {
    log.info("CORS: {}", origins)
    registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins(*origins)
        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS")
}
```

PUT is not allowed by default, as can be seen in `CorsConfiguration#DEFAULT_PERMIT_METHODS`:

```
private static final List<String> DEFAULT_PERMIT_METHODS = Collections.unmodifiableList(
        Arrays.asList(HttpMethod.GET.name(), HttpMethod.HEAD.name(), HttpMethod.POST.name()));
```